# Calculating possible combinations with restrictions

Tags: multinomial-distribution, combinatorics

I have five additives that can be mixed into a chemical.  Each one can be mixed in at a discrete percentage from 0.02% to 0.22% of the chemical (i.e. 0.02%, 0.03%, 0.04%,...0.22%).  Each additive must be present, so mixed in at least 0.02%.  The restriction is that the sum of all percentages cannot exceed 0.3%, but the sum can be less than that, so long as each additive is present.  Without the restriction the answer is easy.  But I can't figure out how to eliminate the number of combinations that would exceed the maximum allowed.  If one additive is mixed at 0.22%, then the other four must be 0.02% each and only that.

Thanks!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha solves this problem [magically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand[%28t^2%2Bt^3%2Bt^4%2Bt^5%2Bt^6%2Bt^7%2Bt^8%2Bt^9%2Bt^10%2Bt^11%2Bt^12%2Bt^13%2Bt^14%2Bt^15%2Bt^16%2Bt^17%2Bt^18%2Bt^19%2Bt^20%2Bt^21%2Bt^22%29^5]+up+to+30).

Comment: BTW: this problem has little to do with statistics,  http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropiate

Comment: I actually just discovered this site and didn't know of the math version.  I'll check there next time.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are new here, you are invited to read this http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

We must count the number of integer points in a 5-D space ($i=1\cdots 5$) with

$n_i=2\cdots 22$ and $\sum n_i \le 30$

A trivial simplification: let $m_i = n_i-2$, so now we have

$m_i=0\cdots 20$ and $\sum m_i \le 20$

This corresponds to an equilateral 5-D tetraedron (standard simplex). And the number of points if given by the [5-simplex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number#Triangular_numbers) (generalization of triangular-tetraedral numbers to five dimensions) :

${21 + 5  -1 \choose 5} = 53130 $

(Notice that the problem was eased because the restrictions eactly coincide with the simplex. If the maximum number were 31 or 29 instead of 30, it would have been a little more difficult)

Answer (score 0):

I made a 5 dimension array of the sums and then counted which ones were below 31. In R:

```
a=b=c=d=e=2:22
```

all combinations of a + b

```
ab=outer(a,b,FUN="+")
```

all combinations of a + b + c

```
abc=outer(ab,c,FUN="+")
```

...

```
abcd=outer(abc,d,FUN="+")

abcde=outer(abcd,e,FUN="+")
```

So the size of `abcde` is 21x21x21x21x21 about 4million entries

```
length(
which(abcde<31)
)
```

Gives:

```
53130
```

If you want the combinations listed use:

```
mixes=(which(abcde<31,arr.ind=T)+1)/100
```

Comment: It may be instructive to compare the computational effort of this solution to `f <- function(t) zapsmall(convolve(t,rep(1,21),type="open")[1:21]); sum(f(f(f(f(s)))))`, which requires only a few hundred basic operations.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @whuber. It takes .3 seconds to run. many times more seconds to type.

Comment: Seth, try generalizing your solution to, say, an eight dimensional array or to sums of 2:102 instead of 2:22 :-).  I will await your answer.

Comment: @whuber is correct; if the question was different my answer would be wrong.

Comment: Seth, you answer is not wrong *per se*: indeed, it nicely illustrates how the combinations can be enumerated. I was only pointing out that the same enumerations can be carried out in a much more efficient way, which could be helpful for future visitors with similar questions.